# Power Generation Via 2 connected objects below distinct orbits

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, newtonian-gravity

As an example:

Large weight A sits just below Earth's orbit

Large weight B sits just below Moon's orbit

A, B are connected by sufficiently strong material (may not exist, and if so how much stronger would it need to be than say, kevlar?). This should create a tension between the 2 objects, which could be used to produce energy.

How many assumptions/constraints have to be made for this to actually work/would it work at all? How much energy could be collected from this before it actually resulted in the disruption of the 2 orbits?

Also, if the problem is specifically impossible for earth, could it apply for some other pair of masses?

Clearly the position of the 2 masses would have to be balanced that the forces acting on them were quite the same. To prevent displacement, there could be some method of correction which would of course also cost energy.

Comment: The tension alone doesn't produce energy. $dW=Fds$, i.e. we need a force and a displacement. The Moon-Earth system does, of course, lose a lot of energy to tidal forces, no strings needed. You can simply install tidal power plants here on Earth and tap into that power directly.